# Get a sub-set of a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
{'key1':1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3}
```

I need to pass a sub-set of that dictionary to third-party code. It only wants a dictionary containing keys `['key1', 'key2', 'key99']` and if it gets another key (eg `'key3'`), it explodes in a nasty mess. The code in question is out of my control so I'm left in a position where I have to clean my dictionary.

What's the best, way to limit a dictionary to a set of keys?

Given the example dictionary and allowed keys above, I want:

```
{'key1':1, 'key2':2}
```

Answer (score 110):

```
In [38]: adict={'key1':1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3}
In [41]: dict((k,adict[k]) for k in ('key1','key2','key99') if k in adict)
Out[41]: {'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

In Python3 (or Python2.7 or later) you can do it with a [dict-comprehension](http://diveintopython3.org/comprehensions.html#dictionarycomprehension) too:

```
>>> {k:adict[k] for k in ('key1','key2','key99') if k in adict}
{'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}
```

Comment: Dict comprehensions are also in Python 2.7.

Comment: I wish there was an operator for this.  Like `adict - {'key1'} == {'key2':2, 'key3':3}`

Comment: There seems to be no sensible inverse of the `dict.update` method

Comment: {k: v for k, v in adict.items() if k in ('key1','key2','key99')} also works nicely.  Just a slight difference.

Comment: @user90038: Thanks for the comment. Note however that if `adict` is huge, `for k,v in adict.items()` requires many iterations. `for k in (...)` requires 3 iterations.

Comment: To make things simpler consider `{k: v for k, v in adict.items() if k in new_keys}` vs. `{k:adict[k] for k in new_keys if k in adict}`.  Don't we face a similar problem in the latter instance if new_keys is large?

Comment: @jlimahaverford: Yes, but there is no indication that that is the problem asked in this question. The OP is asking about what to do if `adict` is too large, and we want to cut it down to a supplied subset of keys.

Answer (score 28):

```
dict(filter(lambda i:i[0] in validkeys, d.items()))
```

Comment: For python 3, that should be `d.items()`.

Answer (score 19):

An other solution without if in dict comprehension.

```
>>> a = {'key1':1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3}
>>> b = {'key1':1, 'key2':2}
>>> { k:a[k] for k in b.keys()}
{'key2': 2, 'key1': 1}
```

Comment: Very pythonic and wins the Least Keystrokes Award too:)

Comment: Correct answer and accounting for giant `a`, not iterating over all of it but only the keys in `b` that are wanted

Comment: I came up with the dict comprehension for a curent project and then thought, "there must be a simpler way to do this." Your answer is that simpler way. Thanks!

Comment: The solution can be even simpler if you define `b` as a list of keys and drop the `keys()` call.

Answer (score 18):

In modern Python (2.7+,3.0+), use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'key1':1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3}
included_keys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key99']

{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in included_keys}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this would be less efficient in case `len(d) >> len(included_keys)` (`>>` denotes "much larger"). But I guess in the common case len(d) isn't very large...

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is the only solution that worked for me. None of the above did.

Answer (score 4):

My way to do this is.

```
from operator import itemgetter

def subdict(d, ks):
    return dict(zip(ks, itemgetter(*ks)(d)))

my_dict = {'key1':1, 'key2':2, 'key3':3}

subdict(my_dict, ['key1', 'key3'])
```

**Update**

I have to admit though, the above implementation doesn't handle the case when the length of `ks` is 0 or 1.  The following code handles the situation and it is no longer an one-liner.

```
def subdict(d, ks):
    vals = []
    if len(ks) >= 1:
        vals = itemgetter(*ks)(d)
        if len(ks) == 1:
            vals = [vals]
    return dict(zip(ks, vals))
```

Comment: I'll often `from operator import itemgetter as ig` to save a bit of horizontal line space and typing.  I don't think I remembered that `itemgetter` would take multiple items to fetch.  Great reminder, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see you like to keep the first 2 elements of the dict, so you can do:

```
>>> {k:a[k] for k in list(a.keys())[:2]}
{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2}
```

Answer (score -1):

With a complex class `Myclass` being a subclass of `collections.UserDict`. To select a subset of it, i.e keeping all its container properties, it's convenient to define a method, e.g. named `sub` like so:

```
def sub(self, keys):
    subset = Myclass() # no arguments; works if defined with only keyword arguments
    for key in keys:
        subset[key] = self[key]
    return subset
```

It is then used as `Myclass.sub([key1, key2 ...]`)

Comment: The answer is neither clear, nor works. `Myclass()` turns out to be undefined.  Also, where to give the original dictionary from which key1, key2 is to be subset ?