# Python extract dictionary key value set

Tags: python, dictionary

I have following example:

```
foo = {'type': 'SOURCE_IP', 'cookie_name': None}
```

I want to extract `type` key and set following variable for `foo`, how do i extract whole key/value set from dictionary?

```
foo = {'type': 'SOURCE_IP'}
```

Comment: you need the function `.items()` ? will give you a set `[('type', 'SOURCE_IP'), ('cookie_name', None)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a sub-set of a Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953371/get-a-sub-set-of-a-python-dictionary)

Comment: If you already know the key name then simply `foo['type']` will give you the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple try this:

```
{'type':foo['type']}
```

output:

```
{'type': 'SOURCE_IP'}
```

Comment: @rdas need to extract 'type' key/value set from dictionary and return {key: foo[key]} return >>> {key: foo[key]}
{'cookie_name': None}

Comment: You're doing a linear search on a data structure that's meant for key-value access. Your whole code is equivalent to simply `foo['type']` - just much, much slower. Once you have the value corresponding to `type` you can format that pair however you want, which will give you: `{'type': 'SOURCE_IP'}`